# How to compose tupled unary functions by combining their input tuples

Tags: scala, shapeless

I've been playing around with shapeless for a bit now.
But, yesterday I got stuck when trying to compose tupled functions.

What I was looking into specifically is composing two unary functions `f1: T => R` and `f2: R => U => S` into `f: TU => S` where T is a TupleN and `TU := (t1, ... , tn, u)`

```
  import shapeless.ops.tuple._

  implicit class Composable[T <: Product, R](val f1: T => R) extends AnyVal{
    def compose2[U, S](f2: R => U => S)(implicit p: Prepend[T, Tuple1[U]]): (p.Out => S) = {
      // how to provide the two required implicits for Last[p.Out] and Init[p.Out]?
      tu => f1.andThen(f2)(tu.init)(tu.last)
    }
  }

  val f1: ((Int, Int)) => Int = x => x._1 * x._2
  val f2: ((Int, Int, Int)) => Int = f1.compose2((y: Int) => (x3: Int) => x3 + y).apply _
```

What I've been struggling with is providing the **implicit proof** for the tuple operations `last` and `init`, so the above code won't compile!

From a logical perspective it feels trivial as result of `Prepend`, but I couldn't figure out a way. So any idea is welcome :)

Using shapeless's facilities to abstract over arity I got somehow closer:

```
  import shapeless.ops.function.{FnFromProduct, FnToProduct}
  import shapeless.{::, HList}

  implicit class Composable[F](val f: F) extends AnyVal{
    // the new param U is appended upfront
    def compose2[I <: HList, R, U, S](f2: R => U => S)
                                     (implicit ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, I => R], ffp: FnFromProduct[U :: I => S]): ffp.Out = {
      ffp(list => f2.compose(ftp(f))(list.tail)(list.head))
    }
  }
  val f1: (Int, Int) => Int = (x1,x2) => x1 * x2
  val f2: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = f1.compose2((y: Int) => (x3: Int) => x3 + y).apply _
```

This works, but then again I was really looking for `compose2` to work on unary tupled `Function1`s. Also, this results in `f: (U, t1, ..., tn) => S` rather than `f: TU => S` with `TU := (t1, ... , tn, u)`.

Comment: Actually, the solution is probably the Undo of Prepend Travis was suggesting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366527/splitting-an-hlist-that-was-concatenated-using-prependa-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Miles says, this would be more convenient with an `undo` for `Prepend`, but since the length of the second part is fixed, an approach similar to the one in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32379975/334519) isn't too bad at all:

```
import shapeless.ops.tuple._

implicit class Composable[T <: Product, R](val f1: T => R) extends AnyVal {
  def compose2[U, S, TU](f2: R => U => S)(implicit
    p: Prepend.Aux[T, Tuple1[U], TU],
    i: Init.Aux[TU, T],
    l: Last.Aux[TU, U]
  ): (p.Out => S) =
    tu => f1.andThen(f2)(i(tu))(l(tu))
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val f1: ((Int, Int)) => Int = x => x._1 * x._2
f1: ((Int, Int)) => Int = <function1>

scala> val f2: ((Int, Int, Int)) => Int =
     |   f1.compose2((y: Int) => (x3: Int) => x3 + y).apply _
f2: ((Int, Int, Int)) => Int = <function1>

scala> f2((2, 3, 4))
res1: Int = 10
```

The trick is adding the output of `Prepend` to the type parameter list for `compose2`—which will generally be inferred—and then using `Prepend.Aux` to make sure that it's inferred appropriately. You'll often find in Shapeless that you need to refer to the output type of a type class in other type class instances in the same implicit parameter list in this way, and the `Aux` type members make doing so a little more convenient.